.Net 6 worker service EF 6 - Repository DI cannot consume scoped service
I have below folder structure in the .Net 6 worker service with EF 6,
Solution file(.sln)
|
|_ Data(.csproj)
|   |_ Models
|   |  |_ DatadbContext.cs
|   |
|   |_ Repository
|      |_ DbRepository.cs
|      |_ IDbRepository.cs
|
|_ Service(.csproj)
   |_ Program.cs
   |_ Worker.cs

In my Program.cs, I have the service configuration as below for dbContext,
services.AddDbContextPool<DatadbContext>(options =>        
options.UseSqlServer(“connectionStringValue”));

Similarly when I try to configure the Repository in the services(repository project reference added in the service project)
services.AddSingelton<IDbRepository, DbRepository>();

On running the application I am getting the below exception

Cannot consume scoped service “Data.Models.DbContext” from singleton “Data.Repository.DbRepository”

I tried configuring Repository as scoped still got the same exception message.
How to add the repository Dependency so the worker service can receive scoped service in constructor

Can you show us  the usage of the repository in the Worker.cs, or wherever you use it. Because configuring your DbRepository as Scoped is the right approach. I could imgine, that you need a Scoped Service in your Worker.cs. You could do that by injecting IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory and then using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope(); with scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbRepository>() - or something like that. But first we have to check your Worker.cs.

Thanks @decius. As per ur suggestion tried to use the IServiceScopeFactory and got the dependency injection of the repository

Ok, to summarize:
You need to have a scopeFactory:
using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbRepository>();

